# Java Xerces jar and Jena

Tags: java, jar, jena, xerces

My issue is summed up nicely here, http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/jena-dev/message/33894  which also proposes a solution.  Problem is stated solution requires access to the code, and I'm only working with a binary distribution of the software.  Anyone know what else I can do, if there's a jar file I can download from somewhere/add to classpath? There's various versions of XercesImpl.jar that I've tried, all resulting in various other errors.  Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: The problem is not described and I cannot access the link.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Jena currently depends (at compile and runtime) on Apache Xerces (i.e. xerces:xercesImpl:2.10.0) therefore Apache Xerces cannot be removed without source code changes.

Xerces is used for RDF/XML parsing and for Datatypes.

In an ideal world, the RDF/XML parsing could be in a separate module (i.e. jena-rdfxml) which would continue to depend on Apache Xerces and the Datatypes would need to be reimplemented without relying on Apache Xerces. This way, you could use a jena-core module with no support for RDF/XML and not dependency on Apache Xerces.

May I ask you why you need or want to remove xercesImpl.jar from your classpath?

See also:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-189
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-191

Comment: reason for this is because the code I was using assumed no XercesImpl.jar was needed, and was provided by Java.  the chlalnege was finding the right jar, which I finally did, perhaps original attempts were pre-version 2.10.0

Answer (score 0):

Since 3.8.0, Jena no longer depends on Xerces: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-1537